# LC-3 Code Segment

Tags: lc3

I am having a difficult time understanding this particular problem.  I have the answers, but I really want to know the reason as to why they are what they are!  I understand how each opcode works, just not in applying it to this problem.....

An engineer is in the process of debugging a program she has written.  She is looking at the following segment of the program, and decides to place a breakpoint in memory at location 0xA404.  Starting with the PC = 0xA400, she initializes all the registers to zero and runs the program until the breakpoint is encountered.

Code Segment:

```
0xA400 THIS1 LEA     R0, THIS1 
0xA401 THIS2 LD      R1, THIS2
0xA402 THIS3 LDI     R2, THIS5
0xA403 THIS4 LDR     R3, R0, #2
0xA404 THIS5 .FILL   xA400
```

Show the contents of the register file (in hexadecimal) when the breakpoint is encountered.

Again, I'm not seeking a list of answers, but an explanation to help me understand what exactly is going on in the program. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the engineer put the breakpoint on line 0xa404 (stopping the program before 0xa404 is run), the code would do the following:

```
0xA400 THIS1 LEA     R0, THIS1  ; LEA loads the address of THIS1 into R0.
                                ; Since THIS1 is at memory location 0xA400, 
                                ; after this instruction R0 = 0xA400

0xA401 THIS2 LD      R1, THIS2  ; LD loads the contents of the memory at
                                ; THIS2 into R1.  Since THIS2 is this very
                                ; line its contents are this instruction,
                                ; which is 0010001111111111 in binary or
                                ; 0x23ff in hex, so after this line executes
                                ; R1 hold 0x23ff

0xA402 THIS3 LDI     R2, THIS5  ; LDI visits THIS5 and treats its value as a
                                ; new memory location to visit.  It visits 
                                ; that second location and stores its 
                                ; contents into R2. In this case, it would
                                ; look at THIS5 and see its value is 0xA400.
                                ; It would then visit 0xA400 and store its
                                ; contents in R2.  0xA400 contains the first 
                                ; line of your program which translates to
                                ; 1110000111111111 in binary, 0xe1ff in 
                                ; hex, so it stores 0xe1ff into R2.

0xA403 THIS4 LDR     R3, R0, #2 ; LDR starts from the memory location of R0,
                                ; adds 2 to that, then stores whatever it 
                                ; finds in that memory location into R3. In
                                ; this case R0 = 0xA400. It adds 2, bringing
                                ; it up to 0xA402, which is the instruction
                                ; immediately above this one.  In binary, that
                                ; instruction is 1010 0100 0000 0001, which
                                ; translates into 0xa401 so the program stores
                                ; the program stores 0xa401 into R3.

0xA404 THIS5 .FILL   xA400
```